# Anyway to get users based on DateTime using Delta API in office 365

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

```
graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=<fields>&$deltatoken=******
```

The above api used to get all users of office365 . But recently we got error message as

```
DeltaLink older than 30 days is not supported.
```

We got the information as **DeltaLink was changed from unlimited to 30 days.** from this link - http://kb.cloudblue.com/en/132418

So We planned to get all users based on date. But I did not found the query param of date on the official document.

Can you help me to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by  getting latest delta token using this query.

```
 https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$deltatoken=latest
```